# Jquery get parent with name not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jm7Kp/

The idea here is to create table dynamically, and the button inside the table creates rows only in that table.

```
<div id="divPrincipal">
</div>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>

<script>
    var objDivPrincipal = $("#divPrincipal");
    var tbl;
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        createTable();
    });

    function createTable() {
        tbl = $("<table border=1><thead><tr><td>FName</td><td>LName</td></tr></thead><tbody></tbody><tfoot><tr><td><button class='btnAddRow'>AddRow</button></td><td></td></tr></tfoot></table></br>");
        objDivPrincipal.append(tbl);
        tbl.find(".btnAddRow").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().after("<tr><td>John</td><td>Snow</td></tr>");
        });
    }
</script>
```

I don't like to use parent().parent().parent()... I tried to use parent('tbody') and closest('tbody') and it didn't work. Even the parent('table').find('tbody') does not work.

Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).closest('table').append("<tr><td>John</td><td>Snow</td></tr>");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Jm7Kp/9/)**

Comment: couldn't you just reference the tbl.find("table") too.  Seems like there is more to be learned here than just this answer

Comment: @Mutmatt- Not sure I follow you. What would you want to use `tbl.find("table")` instead of?

Comment: Since he declares the var tbl and does a tbl = $("blahblahblah") nad then inserts it into the dom tbl is a representation of the jquery object in the dom so a .find may be slightly faster, as they say "More than one way to skin a cat"

Comment: @Mutmatt - Hmmm maybe, although `tbl` always refers to the last newly created table so I'm not sure. Would need to test.

Comment: Will this add the new row on thead or tbody? I did this to add to tbody $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').append("<tr><td>John</td><td>Snow</td></tr>");

Comment: The new row gets added to tbody.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's not in the same ancestry, your add button is in a `tfoot`, so try:

```
$(this).closest("tfoot").prev("tbody").append("<tr><td>John</td><td>Snow</td></tr>");
```

You also want `append` not `after` -- so the above finds the closest `tfoot`, then the previous `tbody`, and appends a new `tr`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm7Kp/7/

Comment: Tks.
Will it be append to the end or the begin of the tbody?